# Recyclerview not showing any items but no errors in log cat

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Before setting the dataset to the adapter, I am getting the book dataset from the Library database, and then I set the data to the adapter and set the adapter to the recycler view. Currently, there are 2 items in the database. The recycler view should show the two books available but it returns nothing. I have tried many different ways in adapter but still can't find any errors on it. I am not sure what is happening can someone help me spot the issue? Thanks in advance for your help.

**single_book_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="15dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#f2f3f4"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:textColor="#353839"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Title"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/author_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
                android:textColor="#a9a9a9"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="Author"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
                android:textColor="#a9a9a9"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:text="Content"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cover_list"
            android:layout_marginStart="-120dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/lib_vid"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
          />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**AllBook.java**

```
package com.example.finalassignment;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AllBook extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Book> bookList;
    All_Book_Adapter allBookAdapter;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_book);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.book_list);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        bookList = new ArrayList<>();
        bookList = databaseHelper.getBookData();

        allBookAdapter = new All_Book_Adapter(this, bookList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(allBookAdapter);
        allBookAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

**All_Book_Adapter.java**

```
package com.example.finalassignment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.List;

public class All_Book_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<All_Book_Adapter.myViewHolder> {

    private List<Book> bookList;
    String uid;
    private Context context;

    public All_Book_Adapter(Context context, List<Book> bookList){
        this.bookList = bookList;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_book_layout,parent,false);
        return new All_Book_Adapter.myViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull All_Book_Adapter.myViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Book book = bookList.get(position);

        byte[] bytes = book.getCover();
        holder.title.setText(book.getTitle());
        holder.author.setText(book.getAuthor());
        holder.description.setText(book.getDescription());

        holder.book_cover.setImageBitmap(Utils.getImage(bytes));

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (context, BookDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("ID", book.getID());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bookList.size();
    }

    public static class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ImageView book_cover;
        public TextView title;
        public TextView author;
        public TextView description;

        public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            book_cover = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cover_list);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_list);
            author = itemView.findViewById(R.id.author_list);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_list);
        }

        void setImageView(Book book){
            byte[] bytes = book.getCover();
            book_cover.setImageBitmap(Utils.getImage(bytes));
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_all_book.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AllBook">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/all_book_toolbar"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/book_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Log Cat**

```
2021-07-19 15:28:10.503 13147-13147/com.example.finalassignment W/finalassignmen: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->getTransitionAlpha()F (light greylist, linking)
2021-07-19 15:28:10.504 13147-13147/com.example.finalassignment W/finalassignmen: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->setTransitionAlpha(F)V (light greylist, linking)
2021-07-19 15:28:10.504 13147-13147/com.example.finalassignment W/finalassignmen: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->setAnimationMatrix(Landroid/graphics/Matrix;)V (light greylist, linking)
2021-07-19 15:28:10.504 13147-13147/com.example.finalassignment W/finalassignmen: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->transformMatrixToGlobal(Landroid/graphics/Matrix;)V (light greylist, linking)
2021-07-19 15:28:10.504 13147-13147/com.example.finalassignment W/finalassignmen: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->transformMatrixToLocal(Landroid/graphics/Matrix;)V (light greylist, linking)
2021-07-19 15:28:10.504 13147-13147/com.example.finalassignment W/finalassignmen: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->setLeftTopRightBottom(IIII)V (light greylist, linking)
2021-07-19 15:28:10.504 13147-13147/com.example.finalassignment W/finalassignmen: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->setTransitionVisibility(I)V (dark greylist, linking)
2021-07-19 15:28:10.517 13147-13147/com.example.finalassignment W/finalassignmen: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/View;->mViewFlags:I (light greylist, reflection)
2021-07-19 15:28:10.519 13147-13147/com.example.finalassignment W/finalassignmen: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->suppressLayout(Z)V (light greylist, linking)
2021-07-19 15:28:12.908 13147-13147/com.example.finalassignment W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@f4e7cee
2021-07-19 15:28:13.070 13147-13211/com.example.finalassignment D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe74c5ec0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe331f110)
```

**GetBookData**

```
    public List<Book> getBookData(){
        List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM book",null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                int bookID = cursor.getInt(0);
                byte[] cover = cursor.getBlob(1);
                String title = cursor.getString(2);
                String author = cursor.getString(3);
                String description = cursor.getString(4);
                String borrower = cursor.getString(5);
                String status = cursor.getString(6);

                Book book = new Book(bookID,title,cover,description,author,borrower,status);
                bookList.add(book);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }else{

        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return bookList;
    }
```

Comment: try to remove `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`

Comment: I tried it, nothing changed :(

Comment: i see. did you check that after this line -  `bookList = databaseHelper.getBookData();`, you have data in `bookList`, before submitting this list to your adapter?

Comment: after that line you can just add `Log.i` or `System.out.println`, and there print out your `bookList` to see if it have any books in it.
I'm just guessing if your method `getBookData()` is async, then maybe you submit the list of book before it got any values in it.

Comment: Yes, there are some items in it after I checked. I'm not sure why it does not display since the list has items in it

Comment: okay so another thing, in your activity_all_book.xml - in `RecyclerView` element, add  this line:
`tools:listitem="@layout/single_book_layout"`

Comment: Okay I tried, still remain blank

Comment: I'm looking at your code again, and really don't see any reason for it not to work. it looks good.
So my guess is to check further the `getBookData()` method. it is async, correct?

Comment: I'm really frustrated as I've checked many times. I've updated my code with getBookData( ) method code. I don't see any problem as it works in other activities. Does navigate from fragment to recycler view in activity affect it?

Comment: I didn't mean that the method is not working, as you already mentioned it's providing you data in other activities. i'm just thinking that its providing you with the list after you send the variable to your adapter. sorry i'm not much of help here, but i just think its best to double check that case by printing the `bookList` that is received in `All_Book_Adapter` constructor.

Comment: I've checked it by printing out the bookList item and it prints two items that are correct. This is so weird :(